Fonts and Images Get loaded multiple times
Some of my resources get reloaded multiple times (see below) even with a preload.

Notice that the fonts are reloaded twice. Same for the Icon-192.png.
What I tried so far:
<link 
   rel="preload" 
   href="assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf"
   as="font" 
   crossorigin>

I tried with and without crossorigin.
